# Swift - scrollViewDidScroll not working with WKWebView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I'm trying to add a shadow to my (custom) nav bar when a user scrolls using `scrollViewDidScroll` but it doesn't do anything. I have the same exact code on another view controller but it has a `tableView` instead of a `WKWebView` and it works fine.

I tried adding `webView.scrollView.delegate = self` but I just get an error.

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var navBar: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addShadow()
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let navigationBar = navBar
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 10
        if offset > 1.5 {
            navigationBar?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
        } else {
            navigationBar?.layer.shadowOpacity = Float(((3 * offset) / 20)/1.5)
        }
    }

    func addShadow() {
        navBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        navBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        navBar.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
        navBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried adding `webView.scrollView.delegate = self` but I just get an error.

You didn't share what the error was. I suspect though that you didn't declare your view controller as [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate) conforming, which caused the compile  time error when trying to set `self` as the scroll view delegate.

Change your view controller declaration to this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
```

Comment: Wow, it actually worked, thanks. But the weird part is that I did actually try adding UIScrollViewDelegate but it was still not working. Weird.